# If $a$ and $b$ are consecutive integers, prove that $a^2 + b^2 + a^2b^2$ is a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, factoring

Problem is as stated in the title. Source is Larson's 'Problem Solving through Problems'. I've tried all kinds of factorizations with this trying to get it to the form $$k^2l^2$$ but nothing's clicking. I tried Bézout but the same expression can be written as $$a^2 + (a^2 + 1)(a+1)^2$$ which would imply that there is no real root.  Would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: @lulu Yeah I have, Im not really quick with factorizations

Comment: That's non-sophisticated... :) Try it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$p^2+(p+1)^2+\{p(p+1)\}^2 =p^4+2p^3+3p^2+2p+1 =(p^2+p+1)^2$$

---

Alternatively,

$$p^2+(p+1)^2+\{p(p+1)\}^2 =(\underbrace{p^2+p})^2+2(\underbrace{p^2+p})+1=?$$

Comment: Could you explain that last factorization?

Comment: @Airdish, Write $3p^2=p^2+2p^2\cdot1$

Comment: Amusingly, when I first saw this answer, the timestamp said "answered 12 seconds ago" and there were already $3$ upvotes!

Comment: Sorry, could you expand a little more? I'm not really getting anything here...

Comment: @Airdish, $$(p^2)^2+(p)^2+1^2+2\cdot p^2\cdot1+2\cdot p\cdot1 +2\cdot p^2\cdot p=?$$

Comment: I'm really sorry, I kinda get what you're aiming at, but I still have no idea what to do after that step. I seriously suck at factorization....

Comment: @Airdish, Please find the alternative method.

Comment: Oh woah, thanks, but still could you explain the first method too please? I'd really like to absorb as much information as possible so I can do these on my own later on.

Comment: @Airdish, What is $$(a+b+c)^2=?$$

Comment: Ohh, I see, that $p^3$ term threw me off. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Airdish. A tip on  finding  a factoring: When $p$ is  large, $p^4+2p^3+3p^2+2p+1=$ $ p^4(1+\frac {2}{p}+\frac {3}{p^2}+\frac {2}{p^3}+\frac {1}{p^4})$ is  close in ratio to $p^4.$ So if it's a  square for all $p$ then it should be $(p^2+f(p))^2 $ where $f(p)/p^2$ is  small when $p$ is large. So try $f(p)=p+g(p),$ because $(p^2+p+g(p))^2,$  when expanded, agrees with it on the first 2 terms (that is, the terms $p^4$ and $2p^3$) , and by inspecting the  expansion, observe that$ g(p)=1 $ will work.  OR you may see $p^4+2p^3+3p^2+2p+1=p^2(p^2+p+1)+p(p^2+p+1)+1(p^2+p+1).$ E.g .$111^2=12,321.$

Answer (score 5):

$$a^2+b^2+a^2b^2=(a-b)^2+2ab+a^2b^2=1+2ab+a^2b^2=(1+ab)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

If $a=b-1$ then square and rearrange to obtain $a^2+2b=b^2+1$. Then
$$a^2+b^2 +a^2b^2=b^2+a^2(b^2+1)=b^2+a^2(a^2+2b)=(a^2+b)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the expression is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, it is not restrictive to assume $b=a+1$, so
$$
a^2+b^2+a^2b^2=
a^2+(a+1)^2+a^2(a+1)^2=
a^4+2a^3+3a^2+2a+1
$$
If you don't see an easy factorization, note that for $a=0$ the statement is clear; for $a\ne0$ we can write
$$
a^4+2a^3+3a^2+2a+1
=
a^2\left(a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}+2a+\frac{2}{a}+3\right)
$$
Now remember that
$$
a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}=\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2-2
$$
so the expression becomes
$$
a^2\left(\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2+2\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)+1\right)=
a^2\left(\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)+1\right)^2=(a^2+a+1)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=\frac{a+b}{2}$, that is if $a<b$, $p=(2a+1)/2$.
\begin{align}(p-\frac{1}{2})^2+(p+\frac12)^2+(p-\frac12)^2(p+\frac12)^2&=(2p^2+\frac12)+(p^2-\frac14)^2\\
&=p^4+\frac32 p^2+\frac{9}{16}\\
&=(p^2+\frac{3}{4})^2
\end{align}

since $p^2=\frac{4a^2+4a+1}{4}$,

$$p^2+\frac{3}{4}=a^2+a+1.$$

Hence, $$a^2+b^2+a^2b^2=(a^2+a+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^2+b^2+a^2b^2 = (a^2+1)(b^2+1)-1$

Then this becomes a special case of the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity:

$
(x^2+y^2)(z^2+w^2) = (xz+yw)^2+(xw-yz)^2
$

Take $x = a, y = 1, z=b, w = 1$ and you get:

$
(a^2+1)(b^2+1) = (ab+1)^2+(a-b)^2 = (a^2+a+1)^2+1
$

since $b = a+1$.